# get lines between two marker patterns where ending pattern is in a specific column

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have to get lines between two marker patterns where the ending pattern has to be present in the third column only. The same ending pattern can be present in the first column as well but have to ignore this case & continue printing till the pattern is found in third column.

for example if the contents are like below & marker patterns are "start" & "stop" in the 3rd column

```
>Line1
>Line2 now stop
>start  
>Line3  
>Line4  
>stop  
>Line6  
>Line7 now stop  
>Line8
```

The output should be

> Line3
>   Line4
>   stop
>   Line6

to get the lines between two patterns i found this
`awk '/start/{flag=1;next}/stop/{flag=0}flag' input.txt`

but that's doesn't apply in my case.Any hints how it can be done through awk or sed. Thanks in advance.

Editing my question as i came across a special case. If there are multiple occurences of the stop pattern & there is one occurence before the start pattern. How to handle this situation.
I have changed the input above to include this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '$1=="start"{p=1; next} p && $3=="stop"{p=0} p' f
Line3
Line4
stop
Line6
```

Comment: for a special case where the stop pattern also occurs before the start pattern, the command will fail. I tried 
awk '$1="start"{p=1;if($3=="stop"){exit}; next}p' file
but didn't work.can you pls help. Thanks.

Comment: How can `end` of something come before `start`? However if you edit the question by providing example of what you want then probably I can suggest something.

Comment: edited the question. The stop pattern has multiple occurences & if one such occurence is before the start pattern then how we will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^start/,/^(\S+\s){2}stop/{//d;p}' file
```